# How to calculate the output of screen -ls?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, array

all. How can I write all sessions into an array? (screen -ls)
i.e:

23257.name_session1 (06/25/2017 10:41:18 PM)(Detached)

22011.name_session2 (06/25/2017 07:50:33 PM)(Detached)

arr[0] = 23257.name_session1;

arr[1] = 22011.name_session2;

example commands: screen -ls | grep -oP '\d+.\S+' | grep -oP '(?<=\d.)\S+'

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=($(screen -ls | egrep -o '\t.+\t' | sort -n))
```

#### Breakdown:

**`arr=($(...))`:** Assigns a series of whitespace-delimited values to an indexed array, e.g. `arr=($(1 2 three 4))` defines `$arr[0]=1`, `$arr[1]=2`, `$arr[2]=three`, and `$arr[3]=4`.

**`screen -ls`:** The base function whose output is to be filtered.  This outputs the following (example) lines:

```
There are screens on:
    79481.ttys000.macbook   (Detached)
    80513.ttys004.macbook   (Attached)
    79513.ttys002.macbook   (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/folders/ht/0ty_c8mx16v69csh949g3rvr0000gn/T/.screen.
```

Note that the white-space on the lines containing the session details are tab-delimited columns.

**`egrep -o '\t.+\t'`:** Selects only the output on each line that falls between two tab characters (includes the tabs).  This isolates the `pid.tty.host` strings.

**`sort -n`:** Sort each line by numerical order, from smallest pid to greatest pid.

The resulting array contains the `pid.tty.host` identifiers for each screen session (both attached and detached), with `$arr[0]` containing the session that started first, through to `$arr[n-1]` containing the *n*th session, started most recently.